# Yellowstone National park is now charging higher entrance fees than before.This should result in:

Tags: supply-and-demand

a. a movement up along the downward sloping demand curve for park visits

b. a decrease in the demand for park visits

c. a movement down along the upward sloping supply curve for park visits

d. an increase in the supply of of park visits

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Remember that a change in price causes a movement along a supply/demand curve.

B. A decrease in demand generally refers to a shift in the demand curve, not just a change in price
C. An increase in price is an upward (not downward) movement along a curve
D. An increase in supply generally refers to a shift in the supply curve, not just a change in price

**A. A movement up along the downward sloping demand curve, resulting in lower quantity consumed.**

I hope this helped!

Comment: https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1662/should-i-downvote-valid-answers-to-off-topic-questions

Comment: Yeah it helped me a lot ,thank you so much :)